# Creating a login form in CodeIgniter based on Ion Auth library

Tags: codeigniter, ion-auth

I'm still learning my way around in CodeIgniter.

I'd like to create a login form in my codeigniter application based on [Ion Auth library](https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth).

I have installed the library following the instruction and it works fine when navigating to auth/login, auth/create_user, auth/logout, etc...

However, I don't need a stand alone page for login, I'd like to embed the form in my homepage. When I use the sample provided login view in my homepage, I get the following errors:

- Message: Undefined variable: message
- Message: Undefined variable: identity
- Message: Undefined variable: password

I realize that the above variables are not defined in my view, I just can't figure out where and how they should be defined and why is that they work fine in the provided sample that came with the library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**config/routes.php**

```
$route['login/check'] = 'auth/my_front_end_login';
```

**view**

```
<?php echo form_open('login/check'); ?>

<fieldset>
    <legend>login Credentials<legend>

    <label for="identity">&lowast; Identity</label>
    <input type="text" name="identity" id="identity" value="<?php echo set_value('identity');?>" />
    <?php echo form_error('identity');?>

    <label for="password">&lowast; Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="<?php echo set_value('password');?>" />
    <?php echo form_error('password');?>

    <label for="message">&lowast; Message</label>
    <input type="text" name="message" id="message" value="<?php echo set_value('message');?>" />
    <?php echo form_error('message');?>
</fieldset>

<?php echo form_close();?>
```

**controllers/auth**

```
public function my_front_end_login(){
   if($this->form_validation->run('login_frontend')) // uses config/form_validation.php
   {
       //validation passed, now attempt login via ION_AUTH
       //open ION_Auth library file and see what the login method requests in its params. 
      if(ION_Auth::login($params)) // Im not familiar with it
      {
         //login success
      }
      else
      {
         //login failure
      }
   }
   else
   {
       $this->index();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. However, I still don't know why the sample view doesn't complain about those variables but my view does. After a little more investigation, looks like ci_vars (that holds those variables: message, identity, ...) is loaded in the sample view, but not it my view. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: As I say im not familiar with ION_Auth but the problem might be in the way the form validation failure is directed, In the above case I simply call the $this->index() method.  Therefore the set_value() vars are available within that scope. ie: the homepage

Answer (score 0):

Do you load proper libraries needed, in controller related to view where you want to embed login form, for example "form_validation" if you use form_input($message) for example, ... anyway you can avoid this by checking if $var is_set.

Comment: form_validation is loaded in my constructor. I can use isset to avoid those errors, I am just curious why the form works fine in the provided sample view, but not in my own view.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo form_open('login/check'); ?>

<fieldset>
    <legend>login Credentials<legend>

    <label for="identity">&lowast; Identity</label>
    <input type="text" name="identity" id="identity" value="<?php echo set_value('identity');?>" />
    <?php echo form_error('identity');?>

    <label for="password">&lowast; Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="<?php echo set_value('password');?>" />
    <?php echo form_error('password');?>

    <label for="message">&lowast; Message</label>
    <input type="text" name="message" id="message" value="<?php echo set_value('message');?>" />
    <?php echo form_error('message');?>
</fieldset>

<?php echo form_close();?>
```