# Ion auth, calling methods?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've been reading this post [Creating a login form in CodeIgniter based on Ion Auth library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9660175/creating-a-login-form-in-codeigniter-based-on-ion-auth-library) but I still have a question about exactly how to call methods in ion auth.

The documentation states:

```
NOTE: Methods available in the model are called through the controller using PHP5 magic. You should never use ion_auth_model->method() in your applications.
```

But then the example shows:

```
$this->ion_auth->login($identity, $password, $remember);
```

If I've autoloaded the Ion_auth library in my autoload.php, exactly how do I call the methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should know that there's a difference between a library and a model. The documentation states that you should never call a method from the model. Instead, load the library and call the methods inside of it. Perhaps you misread that line somehow?

Comment: Hm I just copied and pasted those two lines from the documentation.

Comment: Oh wait, I see what you mean, so I should never do ion_auth_model->login() but $this->ion_auth->login() is ok? Duh.